# Setting tabs inside the HTML page- AngularJS

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I am trying to set the tab in my html page and the code is similar to this:

```
<form name="requestForm">
  <div class="form-group col-md-6 md-padding">
    <div class="text-primary">
        <h3>Create Request</h3>
    </div>

    <div class="tab">
        <button class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event, 'General')">General</button>
        <button class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event, 'Contact')">Contact</button>
    </div>

    <div id="General" class="tabcontent">
        <div>
            <label style="font-size: medium">Contact Name</label>
              ......
        </div>
        <div>
            <label style="font-size: medium">Project</label>
            ......
        </div>
    </div>

    <div id="Contact" class="tabcontent">
        <div>
            <label style="font-size: medium">Site</label>
            .....
        </div>
        <div>
            <label style="font-size: medium">Location</label>
              ....
        </div>
     </div>
     <div class="md-padding col-md-6">
     <div class="row form-group">
       <button type="button" class='btn btn-danger' ng-click="clearRequest(requestForm)">Clear</button>
       <button type="button" class="btn btn-success" ng-disabled="!requestForm.$valid" ng-click="createRequest(requestForm)">Create</button>
     </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

I was hoping that I can see Contact and Project in General Tab, Site and Location in the Contact tab. But it is not working

[image]

I still want the Heading and the buttons at the bottom to stay in all the tabs. What am I missing here?

Adding the snippet [here](http://jsbin.com/cocetumetu/edit?html,css,output)

Comment: I might help you if you show the rest of your code...the Angular part mostly..

Comment: Have your `openCity()` method set a property on the $scope if it doesn't already that id's the current tab. then use `ng-if`, or `ng-show` or `ng-hide` to show/hide the input elements you desire.

Comment: @RandyCasburn I dont have the openCity in my Controller yets. What should the do on the Controller side =. I am new to Angular JS

Comment: @trx - well then, as ZombieChowder says, he _might help if you show the rest of your code - the Angular part mostly_

Answer (score 0):

### ngSwitch

There are several ways to do this, but I think the one you are most looking for (if you do not want to do any handling in your controller) is to use the `ng-switch` and `ng-switch-when` directives:

**Snippet Updated:** *it now shows the General tab as default. Check the controller code comment.*

```js
(function() {
  "use strict";

  var app = angular.module("myApp", []);

  app.controller("myController", myController);

  myController.$inject = ["$scope"];

  function myController($scope) {
    // You can also just use the assignment below to set the General Tab as the default tab (instead of using the Default Template & ng-switch-default directive

    // $scope.showTab = "general";
  }

})();
```

```html
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <title>Show Tabs</title>

  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.6.5/angular.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myController">
  <form name="requestForm">
    <div class="form-group col-md-6 md-padding">
      <div class="text-primary">
        <h3>Create Request</h3>
      </div>

      <div class="tab">
        <button class="tablinks" ng-click="showTab='general'">General</button>
        <button class="tablinks" ng-click="showTab='contact'">Contact</button>
      </div>

      <!-- GENERAL template -->
      <div ng-switch="showTab">
        <div id="General" class="tabcontent" ng-switch-when="general">
          <div>
            <label style="font-size: medium">Contact Name</label> ......
          </div>
          <div>
            <label style="font-size: medium">Project</label> ......</div>
        </div>

        <!-- CONTACT template -->
        <div id="Contact" class="tabcontent" ng-switch-when="contact">
          <div>
            <label style="font-size: medium">Site</label> .....
          </div>
          <div>
            <label style="font-size: medium">Location</label> ....
          </div>
        </div>

        <!-- DEFAULT template -->
        <div id="Default" class="tabcontent" ng-switch-default>
          <div>
            <label style="font-size: medium">Contact Name</label> ......
          </div>
          <div>
            <label style="font-size: medium">Project</label> ......</div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="md-padding col-md-6">
        <div class="row form-group">
          <button type="button" class='btn btn-danger' ng-click="clearRequest(requestForm)">Clear</button>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-success" ng-disabled="!requestForm.$valid" ng-click="createRequest(requestForm)">Create</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </form>
</body>
```

### Explanation - ngSwitch

I did not add any styling changes to your snippet, but the functionality is there.

I do think that it is good practice to move your handling to a controller and create a common / universal html template to use for each tab. But if your tabs will not be loaded dynamically in the future and will remain 2 - 3 tabs,then this will work.

Take a look at the code comments below for a summarized version of how `ng-switch` is working in this scenario:

```
<!-- Create a scope variable and add the name of the form you would like to toggle -->
<div class="tab">
   <button class="tablinks" ng-click="showTab='general'">General</button>
   <button class="tablinks" ng-click="showTab='contact'">Contact</button>
</div>

<!-- Define the switch attribute to evaluate in a container div -->
<div ng-switch="showTab">

    <!-- Shows the 'template' div when your attribute value matches the 'switch-when' condition -->
    <div id="General" class="tabcontent" ng-switch-when="general">
       <!-- Your template html / content goes here -->
    </div>

</div>
```

### ngIf

As the main question commenters have suggested, you can also use the `ng-if` directive for the same result: `<div id="Contact" class="tabcontent" ng-if="showTab === 'contact'">`.

```js
(function() {
  "use strict";

  var app = angular.module("myApp", []);

  app.controller("myController", myController);

  myController.$inject = ["$scope"];

  function myController($scope) {
    $scope.showTab = "general";
  }

})();
```

```html
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <title>Show Tabs</title>

  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.6.5/angular.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myController">
  <form name="requestForm">
    <div class="form-group col-md-6 md-padding">
      <div class="text-primary">
        <h3>Create Request</h3>
      </div>

      <div class="tab">
        <button class="tablinks" ng-click="showTab='general'">General</button>
        <button class="tablinks" ng-click="showTab='contact'">Contact</button>
      </div>

      <!-- GENERAL template -->
      <div id="General" class="tabcontent" ng-if="showTab === 'general'">
        <div>
          <label style="font-size: medium">Contact Name</label> ......
        </div>
        <div>
          <label style="font-size: medium">Project</label> ......</div>
      </div>

      <!-- CONTACT template -->
      <div id="Contact" class="tabcontent" ng-if="showTab === 'contact'">
        <div>
          <label style="font-size: medium">Site</label> .....
        </div>
        <div>
          <label style="font-size: medium">Location</label> ....
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="md-padding col-md-6">
        <div class="row form-group">
          <button type="button" class='btn btn-danger' ng-click="clearRequest(requestForm)">Clear</button>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-success" ng-disabled="!requestForm.$valid" ng-click="createRequest(requestForm)">Create</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </form>
</body>
```

### Explanation - ngIf

`ng-if`, in my mind, is more versatile while `ng-switch` is more single-use (it fits this particular scenario).

The difference is that `ng-if` accepts more than one condition to evaluate `showTab`, whereas `ng-switch` accepts just one.

So if you needed to check `showTab` *and* some other value (e.g. whether all data from the server loaded or a specific object's state), you would use `ng-if`.

Example: `<div id="General" class="tabcontent" ng-if="showTab === 'general' && allDataRetrieved">`

### References to the Angular Directives

- [ngClick](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClick)
- [ngSwitch](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngSwitch)
- [ngIf](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngIf)

Comment: Awesome. But how do I make the General Tab to be clicked as default

Comment: It's in the `ngSwitch` documentation I linked. 

Just add `ng-switch-default` to the tab div you would like to be the default: `<div id="General" class="tabcontent" ng-switch-when="general" ng-switch-default>`

Comment: I dont see ng-switch-default in the documentation as if I give `<div id="General" class="tabcontent" ng-switch-when="general" ng-switch-default>` it doesn't work

Comment: I just updated the snippet to include `ng-switch-default`. My comment above was incorrect usage (sorry). The `ng-switch-default` directive needs to be added to a new div template (reference my snippet) -- I might recommend just setting `$scope.showTab = "general"` in your controller instead. This will do the same thing as `ng-switch-default` but save you from having a whole template div sitting in your markup.

Comment: Updated my answer to include `ng-if`.

Answer (score 0):

This might not be the answer you're looking for, but have you considered using jQuery UI for the tabs if it's only the functionality you're looking for? jQuery UI has an effect called "Tabs Widget" which you can easily implement in your html page